# Spoof referrer when a iFrame is required to open application

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, http-headers, referrer

There is an application which has two demands on opening the application.

First of all it has to be loaded via a iFrame. 2nd of all it has to be loaded from a specific referrer. If one of these isnt true, the application cannot be opened.

My question. Is it possible to work around those demands? So I spoof the HTTP request and I load it in a iFrame in my own website.

Ofcourse I can iFrame the application and ofcourse I can spoof the HTTP request. But I can't figure out a way to do it both, I can't see it. Somebody can help me out?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest creating a PHP file which gets the content of the website hosting the application (take a look [here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10162863-Spoofing-the-HTTP_REFERER&s=6e32a2e299540e0942315ae5b3b22836&p=10162915&viewfull=1#post10162915) for an idea of how to do it), and then using your iframe to display the PHP page you just created.

Comment: You cant do that because the application checks whether your are loading the html page in a iFrame or not.